# Informacion Global Angular 2 TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-2.0, typescript, navegador-web

Sabéis como obtener y utilizar globalmente los siguientes datos del USUARIO en Angular 2 / Typescript:

1. Hora / Fecha
2. Browser
3. Sistema Operativo
4. Dispositivo (Movil - Tablet - Pc)
5. Dimensiones de la ventana
6. Idioma
7. Localización

Comment: Buscando un poco en Google veo respuestas de 1 o 2 líneas para algunos de esos 7 puntos. Probablemente la respuesta completa no llegue a 20 líneas de código. Voto en contra de cerrar por demasiado ámplia.

Answer (score 0):

si te refieres al acceso al objeto $window [aquí](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-get-window-ref/) tienes la forma de hacerlo.

Un saludo.